# Anyone else experiencing trouble with Chrome 49.x and rerenderings?

Tags: rerender, chrome

The code is way to complex to simplify it for this trivial question.
I am changing object fields and variables in my page and Controller Extension.

Worked fine before. But since Chrome updated to 49.x our customers showed us, that these changes are resettet after saving and re rendering parts of the page.
(fields that were changed by picklists and controller variables of type boolean)

Not all, but about 50% of 100 equal tries to reproduce the error failed.

Did anyone else stumbled upon this weird behaviour?